# Empty Iframe from google maps on fancybox reopen?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, iframe, fancybox

Found that when you reopen fancybox with Google maps as iframe - iframe is empty.
See demo [here](http://webdesignandsuch.com/posts/fancybox-google-maps/)

or example

```
<div style="display:none;">
<div id="route-window" >
    <iframe id='i' width="650" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=.+%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0,+%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1,+%D0%B4.+16+%D0%90,+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80.+2&amp;hl=ru&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;sll=47.879165,13.837945&amp;sspn=0.112139,0.308647&amp;hnear=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1.+%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F,+16%D0%90,+%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0,+%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F,+121059&amp;t=m&amp;source=gplus-ogsb&amp;hq=&amp;ll=55.743734,37.565174&amp;spn=0.023191,0.054932&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe> <br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=.+%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0,+%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1,+%D0%B4.+16+%D0%90,+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80.+2&amp;hl=ru&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;sll=47.879165,13.837945&amp;sspn=0.112139,0.308647&amp;hnear=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1.+%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F,+16%D0%90,+%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0,+%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F,+121059&amp;t=m&amp;source=embed&amp;hq=&amp;ll=55.743734,37.565174&amp;spn=0.023191,0.054932&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">Просмотреть увеличенную карту</a></small>
</div>
</div>
```

and init link

```
 $('#link]').fancybox();
```

for link

```
<a href="#route-window" id="link">
```

On second opening - google returns empty iframe :(

Comment: what version of fancybox? if v1.3.4 then you may want to check this http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/d7321b9a4df5b20b

Comment: Yeah! Thanks a lot! The problem was exact described and fixed in article by  your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [JFK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1055987/jfk) for the [link](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/d7321b9a4df5b20b) with the answer

> the issue:  in fancybox v1.3.2+ inline content is "moved" into the
>   fancybox and a  (hidden) temp container is left instead.  the issue
>   occurs when you have iframes tags as inline content.  first time you
>   fire fancybox, the iframe (tag) is moved into fancybox  but once you
>   close the fancybox, the "moved" iframe (tag) moves back  to its
>   original position in the document and it looses the value of  its src
>   attribute and gets a value of "about:blank" hence that the  second
>   time fancybox is fired it just displays an empty (blank) box.
>
> the workaround:  Cache the value of the src attribute while the iframe
>   (tag) is moved  into the fancybox  then restore this value to the
>   iframe tag once fancybox is closed
>
> so your script should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  var mySRC ="";  
  $("a.fancybox").fancybox({  
     'padding': 0,  
     // other API options etc  
     'onComplete': function() {  
         mySRC = $('#inlineParent iframe').attr('src');  
     },  
     'onClosed': function() { 
         $('#inlineParent iframe').attr('src',mySRC);  
     }  
  }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

**NOTE** : this is for fancybox v1.3.4 only

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to have a blank holding div somewhere on page i.e.

```
<div style="display:none" id="fb"></div>
```

And have an on complete to clone the item/iframe etc into there on loaded modal

```
'onComplete': function() {
    $('#fb').append($(this.href).clone());
},
```

It does mean you will duplicate the item on the page and have 2 instances while the modal is open and once closed it will be in a different hidden div to where is began.